# VO Pop Screens that do the least coloration.

Tags: recording, microphone, windscreens

Does such a thing exist?

What I'm looking for is a pop screen that does the least coloration of the voice. I'll be using it on U87s, 414s, basically, any VO mic.

What do you use for your VO and vocal recordings?

Also, does foam protection sound any good on a U87? I've seen photos of people putting foam socks onto U87s. I can't imagine those sound very good (high-end loss).

Did you search to find one that does the least amount of coloration to the sound?

Does anyone still use the old nylon-on-the-coathanger trick?

Thanks!

- Ryan

Comment: I guess my ears need more training, I've never noticed that before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of the [Sterling Audio](http://www.guitarcenter.com/Sterling-Audio-STPF1-Professional-Pop-Filter-103722146-i1165171.gc) metal pop filter.  I use it with my C414 all the time.  Sounds great, and you can just wash it off with a cloth when done.  Doesn't smell like the fabric ones do!

It has a nice long neck too.

I've not noticed any high end loss with it.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://studioprojects.com/pop.html) little guy might do the trick for you? I've used it once, but it was to long ago, i don't really remember how it performed.

Comment: I have one of those at my studio.. it works great but it can be a little bit noisy sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I like the Avantone PS-1 Pro Shield -- another metal one, easily cleaned, doesn't color, and works great. Use 'em all the time!

--jpf

Answer (score 1):

+1 on the metal filters. We've got a number of these Stedman's that I prefer to the nylon filters: http://www.stedmancorp.com/pages/ps101.html

Comment: That's the exact one I have.